# Python - Tensorflow - LSTM- ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_16 to have shape (None, 100) but got array with shape (16, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, keras-2

Could someone help me to understand what this error is all about?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(82, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=1000))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 5, batch_size=64)
```

When i run this LSTM model, I am getting an error as

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_16 to have shape (None, 100) but got array with shape (16, 2)
```

I am not sure how much the below information would be useful:

```
x_train.shape
Out[959]: (16, 1000)

y_train.shape
Out[962]: (16, 2)
```

If you need any other information, I am ready to provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have defined dense layer input shape is 100.

```
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

so you need to make sure your input should always same shape.
here in your case make x_train and and y_train same shape.

try with :

```
model = Sequential()
# here the batch dimension is None,
# which means any batch size will be accepted by the model.
model.add(Dense(32, batch_input_shape=(None, 500)))
model.add(Dense(32))
```

Comment: Thanks this has worked for me. however 32 has not worked, I have chosen Dense(2, batch_input_shape=(None,500))). this has worked. Would it be possible for you to explain me the fundamental behind this please. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome. that it helped you. and hey, i just gave you a prototype or example. parameter you need to make change !!. :)

Comment: I have raised one more question. I beleive you would be the right person to answer. If you are aware, kindly guide me (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634434/different-accuracy-at-every-run-of-lstm-model)

Answer (score 1):

Your last layer has an output shape of None,100

```
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

But your data (y_train) has the shape (16,2). It should be

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```